# HttpWebRequest return error 500 when GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get a response from SOAP webservice, but I'm falling into a webexception Error 500.

This my class to get a response:

```
public static string getResponse()
{
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    //xml.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>");
    xml.Append(@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:br=""http://www.totvs.com.br/br/"" >").Replace(@"\", "");
    xml.Append("<soap:Envelope/>");
    xml.Append("<soapenv:Body>");
    xml.Append("<br:RealizarConsultaSQLAuth>");
    xml.Append("<br:codSentenca>GLOBAL_054</br:codSentenca>");
    xml.Append("<br:codColigada>0</br:codColigada>");
    xml.Append("<br:codAplicacao>V</br:codAplicacao>");
    xml.Append("<br:Usuario>xxxx</br:Usuario>");
    xml.Append("<br:Senha>xxxx</br:Senha>");
    xml.Append("<br:parameters>codcoligada=1;codsistema=V;codusuario=mestre</br:parameters>");
    xml.Append("</br:RealizarConsultaSQLAuth>");
    xml.Append("</soapenv:Body>");
    xml.Append("</soapenv:Envelope>");
    string s = getUKMailData(xml.ToString(), "http://xxx.xxxx.com.br:99/xxxx/wsConsultaSQL.asmx");
    return s;
}

public static string getUKMailData(string xml, string address)
{
    string result = "";
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(address);
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
    string teste = xml.Replace(@"\", "");
    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(teste);
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                result = soapResult;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
    return result;
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("username", "xxx");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("password", "xxx");
    // webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    return webRequest;
}
```

anyone can help me? I already read a series of articles that unfortunately did not help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Error 500 means the server encountered an error processing your request in some way. A well designed API will indicate what happened with a further code and a response message. For example `500.13` is that the webserver is busy. Look at the content of the response, it may contain a message such as "Value for 'Usuario' is invalid". It's unlikely that we can guess what's wrong by just reading this (non-English I might add) code.

Answer (score 0):

Your request maybe true but server-side doesn't know how to process your data. Maybe parameters which are sent fault. Please check your server-side so end-point.